# $x^p -x-1$ irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

Show that $x^p - x -1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$.

I've seen this polynomial (or some variation x^p -x -a) on several of our qualifying exams and in every case they ask you to show it is irreducible. I know you can show it is irreducible by showing that if $\alpha$ is a root of it then $\alpha+1$ is also a root and then showing that it is the minimal polynomial for its roots. This takes about half a page of writing to do and I am looking for a shorter way to prove this.

> Anyone have a shorter way?

Comment: A big hint: Fermat's little theorem shows that it can't have any linear factors - why?

Comment: Several short ways [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/81583/11619). My answer is possibly the most elementary, but others' arguments are much shorter!

Comment: Here's [another thread with a short solution](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1256088/264)

Comment: If $q$ is a prime power and $a\in\mathbb{F}_q$ is nonzero, then $x^q-x+a$ is also irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_q[x]$.

Comment: Weird. Marked as duplicate but when I was typing up the question that never came up as a "similar problem that might have my answer"

Comment: @StevenStadnicki just because it doesn't have linear factors doesn't mean it's irreducible though

Comment: @Batominovski: I don't think that's right. Check your source (and/or recalibrate your intuition :-). And look at [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/122274/11619).

Comment: @Andrew: It often happens that you see better matches in the "Related" list (see the right margin). I don't know how the system works. The local search engine has problems with TeX-parts (may be it cannot use it at all?). Don't worry about it.

Comment: And, if you don't find those answers satisfactory @-ping me and explain what else you think could be simplified. Any moderator can reopen this with a single click, but they may not want to overrule me :-/

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen, you are right.  I misremembered the problem.  I know there is a similar problem that doesn't require the field to be $\mathbb{F}_p$.  Let me state it here.  Let $F$ be a field of characteristic $p$ with $p$ being prime.   Then, $x^p-x+c$ is irreducible in $F[x]$ if and only if $x^p-x+c$ has no root in $F$.